# Injectivity Unclear

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R=K[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ and $m$ be  maximal ideal of $R.$ Let $(s_1,...,s_d)$ be a base of $m/m^2$ where $\dim R_m=\dim_K m/m^2=d.$ Then by Kunz Chapter V.5.10 the canonical epimorphism

\begin{eqnarray}K[y_1,...,y_d]&\longrightarrow& gr_{m}(R_m), \\ y_i&\mapsto& s_i+m^2\end{eqnarray} is an isomorphism.

(See the book of Kunz, Introduction to Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Geometry. For the sake of simplicity I assume K=L).

I have no problems in understanding this part.

Then I saw in some paper that from the above statement follows the canonical $K$-algebra homomorphism

$$K[y_1,...,y_d]\longrightarrow R$$

is injective. I cannot see why this is so straightforward.

Comment: Actually the question is, if  (s_1,..,s_d)  is a base of the tangent space $m/m^2$ of a smooth point, is it straightforward to say that  there is an injective $K$-algebra homomorphism    $K[y_1,...,y_d]\longrightarrow R,$ $y_1,...,y_d$ are any further indeterminates.

Comment: @user26857 $s_i'$s are in $m/m^2,$ they are equivalence classes modulo $m^2.$

Comment: @user26857  I have deleted your comment while i was deleting my comment, sorry for that.  The base of the cotangent space $m/m^2$ is  (s_1,...,s_n). Since the dimension of the local ring $R_m$ is equal to the dimension of the $m/m^2$ the local ring is smooth and the $s_i$'s are regular sequence.   The elements of the cotangent space are actually equivalence classes modulo $m^2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I see how things work:

The canonical homomorphism $$K[Y_1,\dots,Y_d]\to K[\bar s_1,\dots,\bar s_d]=gr_m(R_m)$$ given by $Y_i\to \bar s_i$, where $\bar s_i=s_i+m^2$, is an isomorphism. Then we consider the homomorphism $$K[Y_1,\dots,Y_d]\to K[s_1,\dots,s_d]$$ given by $Y_i\to s_i$, and followed by the inclusion $K[s_1,\dots,s_d]\subset R$. The last one is injective, and let's show the first is also injective. This indeed follows easily from the above isomorphism: if $f\in K[Y_1,\dots,Y_d]$ is such that $f(s_1,\dots,s_d)=0$, then by taking the residue classes we get $f(\bar s_1,\dots,\bar s_d)=0$, so $f=0$.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  When you consider the residue classes in the last line  $\bar{s_{i}},$ are they modulo the ideal $I$ or  $m^2?$

Comment: Modulo $m^2$. (Actually I've sent $f(Y_1,\dots,Y_d)$ to $gr_m(R_m)$ via the given canonical isomorphism.)